# Moving html <audio> and <button> elements in to JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, element

I've been tasked in a University practice sheet to move the  and  elements from the html  into the JavaScript for loop instead because apparently, it will be easier to edit the players. I've been trying to do so but I cant seem to get it working. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated!

Thank you,

Archie

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drum sounds with audio tags</title>

        <style>
            div#audioElements {
                display: block;
                background-color: rgb(100,250,90);
            }

            div#padArea {
                float: top;
                height: 50%;
                background-color: rgb(220,100,20);
            }

            button.drumPad {
                height: 30%;
                margin: 3px;
                background-color: rgb(190,100,180);
                font-size: 6em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Drum sounds with audio tags</h1>

        <div id="audioElements" width="100%">
            <h2>Audio elements</h2>
            <audio controls id="audio1"></audio>
            <audio controls id="audio2"></audio>
            <audio controls id="audio3"></audio>
            <audio controls id="audio4"></audio>
        </div>

        <div id="padArea" width="100%">
            <h2>Trigger pads</h2>
            <button id="pad1" class="drumPad">1</button>
            <button id="pad2" class="drumPad">2</button>
            <button id="pad3" class="drumPad">3</button>
            <button id="pad4" class="drumPad">4</button>
        </div>


        <script>
            var players = []; // empty array
            var pads = [];


             for(var i=1; i<=4; i++) {

                pads[i] = document.getElementById("pad" + i);
                pads[i].addEventListener("mousedown", padActions);
             players[i] = document.getElementById("audio" + i);
            players[i].src = "sound" + i + ".mp3";
            players[i].load();
             }

            /*
             padActions() callback function triggers an audio player in
             the players[] array depending on which trigger pad activated
            */
            function padActions(event){
                var padThatWasClicked = event.target;
                var padIndexInArray = pads.indexOf(padThatWasClicked);

                players[padIndexInArray].currentTime = 0; //rewind audio
                players[padIndexInArray].play();
            }

            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A place to start would be looking at adding the names of your audio files to an array (e.g. `var clips = ['audio1.mp3', 'audio2.mp3']`).

This way, instead of writing a for-loop between 1 and 4, you could loop through `clips.length`. That way, if there are more than four clips, you don't have to change that line of code.

But inside the loop, you're still depending on the fact that there's going to be HTML markup that matches, for example, a button with the ID of `pad4`. And if you add more audio clips, that might not still be true.

So instead of hoping that the `<button id="pad5">` element is there, you could use the loop to create it! Look into `document.createElement()` (documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)).

Good luck!